# i have run the pvar model, but i am not able to run the irf plot, it is giving me error that it is not positive semi definite

Tags: stata

This is part of the result I got after I ran pvar, but I am not able to generate irf plots out of this

[image: img1]

```
pvar z lag_z avepath1 
pvar z lag_z avepath1 age_15_40
pvar z lag_z avepath1 age_15_40 age_40_65
pvar z lag_z avepath1 age_15_40 age_40_65 age_65_above //* it is becomeing slow from here
pvar z lag_z avepath1 age_15_40 age_40_65 age_65_above ExchangeRate 
pvar z lag_z avepath1 age_15_40 age_40_65 age_65_above ExchangeRate CPI
```

This is the code that I ran.

It is n unbalanced panel, I tried running pvar, but now it is not generating irf plots and giving me error that it is not positive definite

[image: img2]